# pointer with equality operator ( problem! )

Tags: c, pointers, assignment-operator

**why equality operator with the pointer on function char (*checker ) has no effect on actual string**

```
#define MAXLINE 20
   char strings[MAXLINE];
   char nl[]= "\n";
   char space[]= " ";
   char tab[]= "\t";
   char *tab_p=tab;
   
   int i=0,j=0,c;
   char *s;
   //char* t;
   
   char *checker(char *cp);//function checks for \n,\s,\t
   
   int main()
   {
       while ( (c=getchar() )!= EOF )
           strings[i++]=c;
   
       s=checker(strings);//s gets address return value
   
       while(*(s+j) != '\0'){
           printf("%c",*(s+j));
           j++;
       }
   }
   
   char *checker( char *cp)
   {
       while( *(cp+i) != '\0'){
           if(*(cp+i) == *tab_p) /* this condition is not applied why?*/
               *(cp+i)= '\b';
           i++;
       }
   
       return cp;
   
   }
```

** I am trying to replace the tab in the original string with backspace and return the modified string but the equality operator have no effect on the original string .**
**could anyone help me through this.**

Comment: Stop writing things like `*(cp+i)`.  Instead use `cp[i]`.  Don't fight the language.

Comment: The problem is due to `checker` using a global variable for `i`, which is insane.  That global variable has the last value that was written to it in `main` (which is also insanely using a global).  In other words, it indexes the character past the end of the string.  Also, you forgot to null-terminate your string.  Lots of bugs here.

Comment: Any reason why you define a char array to hold a tab character and another variable to point there and then dereferencing it instead of just use `'\t'`? You could simply use `if(cp[i] == '\t')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused in part by abusing global variables.

When you enter `checker`, the value of the global `i` is already set to the length of the string.  So the `while` loop is not entered.

Move all of the global variables into the functions where they're needed.  Specifically, move them all to `main` and also add `i` to `checker`.

```
#define MAXLINE 20
char *checker(char *cp);

int main()
{
   char strings[MAXLINE] = {0};

   int i=0,j=0,c;
   char *s;

   while ( (c=getchar() )!= EOF )
       strings[i++]=c;

   s=checker(strings);

   while(*(s+j) != '\0'){
       printf("%c",*(s+j));
       j++;
   }
}

char *checker( char *cp)
{
   char tab = '\t';
   int i=0;

   while( *(cp+i) != '\0'){
       if(*(cp+i) == tab)
           *(cp+i)= '\b';
       i++;
   }

   return cp;
}
```

Comment: It would be more efficient to simply write a `'\0'` to the end of `strings` rather than dynamically writing zero to each and every element.  In general, you want to avoid using initializers for non-static arrays, since they're rarely needed and they result in runtime overhead.  C originally didn't even allow them.

Comment: @kshitizghimire Note that this solution does something it shouldn't, which is it dynamically initializes an automatic array as a lazy way of writing a null character to the end (it actually writes it to the *entire* array).  Instead, you should remove the initializer, and add `string[i] = '\0';` after the `while` loop in main.  That way your grader won't deduct points for an inappropriate array initializer.  You should also check to make sure you don't write past the end of the array (that check is missing from both versions).

Comment: @TomKarzes the implementation might zero-initialize local variables as a security measure, in which case writing a `\0` would be inefficient.  The original initializer is good style IMO and your point is , in the best case, a pico-optimization that would not be detectable in any benchmark.  (The code should check for buffer overflow obviously)

Comment: @TomKarzes Initializers for automatic variables have always been allowed, even in K&R.  In C99 the requirement for the initializer to be a constant expression was relaxed.  Also the historical behaviour of C  is hardly relevant to writing new code -- would you also argue that function prototypes should not be used, since C originally didn't have them?

Comment: @M.M You are absolutely wrong.  Yes, initializers have always been allowed for automatic variables in C, but *not* for arrays.  Here is a direct quote from K&R, page 83:  "Automatic arrays may not be initialized".  I'd say that's pretty clear-cut.  And no, I'm not arguing that new language features should be avoided.  I'm arguing that not all new features are good.  In particular, I consider allowing initializers for automatic arrays to be bad, because it is almost never necessary and it is always inefficient.

Comment: @M.M I would argue that C is a low-level language that should be used when efficiency is important, or when direct access to system calls is important.  As such, Things like initializing an entire array as a lazy way to null-terminate a string make no sense.  It's bad code, and a good grader would take points off for it.  If efficiency isn't an issue, when why use C?  Use Python instead.

Comment: @TomKarzes micro-optimization is something you might do at the end of development, where you have benchmarks set up, not in a toy program while learning the language. And there are plenty of reasons to use C.  "Micro-optimize or don't use the language" is a ridiculous (and elitist) position to take.

Comment: @M.M I realize that newer versions of C have been junked-up with a lot of unnecessary runtime overhead to deal with people who aren't able to code in a language like C, and I'm strongly against it.  The whole point of C is that it's ultra-lightweight, and very low-level (basically a portable assembler).  If you want lots of extra runtime baggage, use C++.

Comment: @M.M It's not a micro-optimization.  It's basic good programming style.  As I said, if you think dynamically writing an entire array with 0 is the best way to null-terminate a string, then C is the wrong language for you.  You should be using an interpreted language with lots of runtime training wheels.  C is for people who can code without training wheels, or at least it used to be.

Comment: @TomKarzes IMO basic good programming style is safety-first and micro-optimization last. Zero-initializing an array is good from a safety perspective. It's also good from a maintenance perspective: the code is easy to read and there is no possibility of a mistake in the code to add a null-terminator.   You're entitled to your opinion on code style but don't pretend your way is somehow the only acceptable way or that a "good reviewer" automatically agrees with you.

Comment: @M.M You're entitled to your opinion, but I disagree with most of your technical points.  In particular:  (1) We're all familiar with the programming adage "premature optimization is the root of all evil".  But the intent of that adage is that one shouldn't *overly complicate* one's code for the sake of efficiency unless that efficiency is truly needed.  But that doesn't apply here, because adding an explicit assignment of `\0` to the end of the string is *clearer* and *less error-prone* than relying on an initialization that's several lines above the code that sets the string.

Comment: @M.M So the tradeoff here is a win-win:  Not only is the explicit assignment faster, but it's also clearer.  You don't have to wonder where the last reference to the array was, and whether it's guaranteed to still be all-zero.  You've basically eliminated a dependency by making the assignment explicit.

Comment: @M.M And (2) This is hardly a "pico-optimization".  In practice, zero-filling the entire array can take a significant amount of time.  Now, granted, in this example the array is tiny, but a more realistic size would be something like 1000 characters, and in that case, eliminating the code to dynamically zero the array could be significant, especially if the average string size was tiny.  Plus it results in less code to do a single assignment rather than to have a loop that zeros all elements.

Comment: @M.M And again, C is not meant to be a teaching language with lots of safety nets like, say, Pascal.  It's meant to be lean and fast.  Zeroing every array to protect yourself from bugs is using a sledge hammer where tweezers are indicated.  If a programmer relies on that, then all it really means is they don't understand their code.